# General cleaning solution for clinical chemistry applications

Tags: biochemistry, spectroscopy, chemical-biology, cleaning

I want to reuse some plastic and glass items that I am using to do colorimetric concentration analysis of serum and urine. There are some enzymatic assays, mineral assays and so on. I have been trying to soak in hydrochloric acid (pH 1.5) for 30 minutes and rinse in distilled water. But it seems the items are not satisfactory clean because when I use them, it seems drops cling to the surface as if there are microscopic impurities on the surface.

What is recommended for cleaning in this situation?

Comment: I used to use chromic acid for cleaning glassware for analytes in HPLC applications, and it worked very well. [This guide](https://dec.vermont.gov/sites/dec/files/wsm/wastewater/docs/GlassCleaning.pdf) might be of use.

Comment: Please don't suggest chromic acid. It is too dangerous and carcinogenic. We have no idea of the student's handling expertise. Plastic cuvets have to land in garbage.

Comment: Likely, there won't be one solution to everything for the history (what kind of sample/sample digest/derivatization) took place in the container made of glass or plastic.  «Plastic» itself comprises a wide range of polymers with different resistance toward chemicals, too.  I speculate biology.se is better suited to answer this kind of question with currently 500 entries found for keyword «cleaning», including [this one](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/46463/what-kind-of-detergent-should-i-use-in-cell-culture-laboratory-for-cleaning-purp).